# Access to ToggleButtons in ListView

Tags: android, listview, get, position, togglebutton

I am using Custom Adapter (ListAdapter.java) that extends ArrayAdapter to fill ListView (List.java).
After that ListView row contains TextView and ToggleButton.

In List.java I can register click on ListView row:

```
sett_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View view, int position, long id) {
```

but how can I register click on ToggleButton, and get row position of that button?

**EDIT: @MDMalik**

In ListAdapter.java:

A):

```
View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.option);
        final ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.toggle);
```

B):

```
if (values2[position].equals("on")) {
            toggle.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            toggle.setChecked(false);
        }
```

C):

```
toggle.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
        toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.valueOf(position) + " : Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });
```

That's it. Now I have position of clicked button. Thank you.

**How can I write result to database now?**

Something like this (not working):

```
toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (toggle.isChecked() == true) {
                        checked = 1;
                        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("database.db", null);
                        myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + TableName + " SET  on_off_ = 'on' WHERE sett_ = '" + values[position] + "'");
                        myDB.close();
                    } else {
                        checked = 0;
                        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("database.db", null);
                        myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + TableName + " SET  on_off_ = 'off' WHERE sett_ = '" + values[position] + "'");
                        myDB.close();
                    }

             }
        });
```

Comment: do mean how to know if it is selected or not?

Comment: yes, and in which row (position) is selected button.

Comment: and what are you passing in CustomAdapter. because that is most important

Comment: final SettingsAdapter adapter = new SettingsAdapter(this, str, on_off_str);
      sett_list.setAdapter(adapter);
Just string [] with text for textview and string [] with on or off state for toggle button.

Comment: i meant is a list, string [], hashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) As you have a CustomAdapter, you need to intalize your ToggelButton in getView.

B) Your String array should have a default value for that button, either true or false that can be achieve something like this

```
String chkCondition = hmap.get("chk").toString().toLowerCase();
Boolean blnChk = true;
if (chkCondition.equals("false"))
{    blnChk = false;   }
chkBox.setChecked(blnChk);
```

C) Then you need to declare onClickListener for that where is basically reintallize your origianl array finding your TextView value and the new `chk` value.

```
private void setCheckValue(String Condition, String upc) {
  for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
     String Upccode = data.get(i).get("UpcCode").toString();
     if (Upccode.equals(upc)) {
        HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hmap = data.get(i);
        hmap.put("chk", Condition);
        data.set(i, hmap);
        break;
     }
  }
}
```

D) Returning the modified data to the Activity by declaring a method call `getData()`

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

I use `data` in my CustomAdapter. `Data` is a `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` .

**Edit** I don't do SQL command on toggle change. I collect them in a array. Then you obviously have a `Submit` button in your Activity. Once you press the submit button. I get the `Data` from the `CustomAdapter`. Which is done by `getData()` this will give you HashMap in your Activity.

Comment: I don't have a submit button... ToggleButton is my submit button. Can I do SQL command directly from Adapter with toggle?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to achieve this by setting usual listeners inside `Adapter` when inflating `View` in `getView` and also remembering position for that `View` inside tag.

Take a look at this working example: [ButtonsProblemsExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-lists-adapters-demo/blob/master/ListsAndAdapters/src/pl/mg6/programistamag/linad/ButtonsProblemsExampleActivity.java).

Comment: @mgulan Plenty of code in my demo project. You can even download and run it.